# How do I reference system.drawing in F# source file (fs). It works for script files (fsx)

Tags: dll, bitmap, f#, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently coding in F# using Visual Studio 2015

I'm trying to access the .Net Namespace System.Drawing to make a bitmap. I've been supplied with a working example project from school that draws a bitmap and updates it every second. The file is a F# script file with extension .fsx

The thing is i'm not able to access the System.Drawing namepace and use the same code if I copy and paste it into a F# source file, with the extension .fs.

Visual studio's intellisence is not even showing the .Drawing namespace.

I've tried googling around, but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio

From menu: View -> Solution Explorer

[image]

Expand the project. In this example it is ConsoleApplication2

[image]

Right click references

[image]

Click Add Reference...

[image]

[image]

On left click Assemblies
Framework should be selected by default. If not select Framework

[image]

In upper right for search.
When entering the search term **do not** press Enter when done.
For search enter: drawing

[image]

In middle
Click on System.Drawing

[image]

Click box on left of System.Drawing

[image]

Click OK

Expand References

[image]

Verify reference to System.Drawing added.

In fs file at top add following line

```
open System.Drawing
```

[image]

You can now use the the library, e.g.

[image]

### Microsoft notes

For a complete example of creating a project see:

[Walkthrough: Using Visual F# to Create, Debug, and Deploy an Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee241127(v=vs.140).aspx)

The part about adding references is under

> To develop a component by using F#

and is  item 3.

> Open the shortcut menu on this project's References node, and then
>   choose Add Reference. Choose the Solution node, and then choose the
>   Projects node. Select the check box next to the RateAnalysis project,
>   and then choose the OK button

.

Comment: you're a master. Thank you deeply